# Intersystems cache db - specific ROWSPEC dynamically

Tags: intersystems-cache

I can do this:

```
Query All() As %Query(CONTAINID = 1, ROWSPEC = "Title:%String,Author:%String")
{
}
```

But I need to specify ROWSPEC dynamically. I have globals like this:

```
^glob("title1","author1","xxKZ1") = "val1"
^glob("title1","author1","ssn","xyPO2") = "val2"
^glob("title2","author2","xxII8") = "val3"

^globNext("key1") = "val1"
^globNext("key1","key2") = "val2"
```

So I need to dynamically create structure of query row. For ^glob I need have something like this:

```
Query All() As %Query(CONTAINID = 1, ROWSPEC = "Prop1:%String, Prop2:%String, Prop3:%String, Prop4:%String, Val:%String")
    {
    }
```

For ^globNext I need something like:

```
Query All() As %Query(CONTAINID = 1, ROWSPEC = "Prop1:%String, Prop2:%String)
    {
    }
```

Is it possible to reach it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible, because number of columns have to be fixed. But as your code generate result, you can define some columns like `Prop1`, `Prop2`...`PropN`, and in result return as many columns as you need, and any last columns just well be null. And after that in your client-side code you cant get access by its like `Value`.

Comment: You mean I will have 1000 props (cols), and will use only first 5 for example? And last columns will be null?

Comment: Yes, it is, in your code `Fetch` code just add as a result to `s Row=$lb("val1","val2")` or even so, `s Row=$lb("name:val1","name:val2")`

Comment: Ok, I will consider It and possibly try it. Thanks